# Kafka or Airflow for automation

Tags: airflow

I would like to automate some of my tasks using Apache Kafka. Previously i
used to do the same using Apache Airflow and which worked fine. But i want
to explore the same using Kafka whether this works better than Airflow or
not.

1. Kafka runs on Server A
2. Kafka searches for a file named test.xml on Server B, here kafka search
   for every 10 or 20 mins whether this file created or not.
3. Once kafka sense the file created, then the job starts as follows
   a)Create a jira ticket and update all the executions on jira for each
   events
   b) Trigger a rsync command
   c) Then unarchive the files using tar command
   d) Some script to execute using the unarchive files
   e) Then archive the files and rsync to different location
   f) Send email once all task finished

Please advise if this is something kafka intelligent to begin with? Or if
you have any other open source products which can do this actions , please
let me know. By the way i prefer to setup these on docker-compose based
installation.

Or please suggest, what are the best opensource tools available for this automation purpose

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using kafka for the usecases you mentioned. Kafka is not good for defining dags or workflows. It works great for streaming usecase(data in motion).

Airflow would allow to define dags with multiple task.
You can leverage filesystem sensor[https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/sensors/filesystem.py] to check if file/folder has been updated/created.

And post that you can leverage python operators and other operators(hooks) to achieve all other task as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with that statement .
Of course , Kafka is able to build data pipelines (Dags/ Topologies) with KStream or KSQLDB in a durable, resilient and highly scalable fashion.